# How to add navigation bar to PyDev?

Tags: python, pydev, navigationbar

I am trying to add navigation bar to PyDev, something like [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm).

Is this navigation bar Breadcrumb for Java only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone still needs an answer, I found [this](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/download/) plugin that does the job for me... :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is java only (there's nothing really on the platform to implement it, all the code is inside JDT, the java plugin).